# Invalid argument supplied for checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

My site is showing this warning:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /admin/insert.php on line 37

I have used this php code for data insert in mysql database from checkbox

How can I solve it?

Thanks

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFEBC1"> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="E1[]"value="1" >
                国語
            <input type="checkbox" name="E1[]" value="2" >
                算数
            <input type="checkbox" name="E1[]" value="3" >
                理科
            <input type="checkbox" name="E1[]" value="4" >
                社会 
            <input type="checkbox" name="E1[]" value="5" >
                英語
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

```
<?php 
$ele_school = $_POST['E1'];
$selected_schoo2 = "";
foreach ($ele_school as $ele_school2 ) {
    $selected_schoo2 .= $ele_school2 . ", ";
}
$selected_schoo2 = substr($selected_schoo2, 0, -2);
$query="insert into  person(id,login_date,name,selected_schoo)
     values('$_POST[PID]',
    '$_POST[REGISTRATION]',
    '$_POST[FURIGANA2]',
    '$selected_schoo2')";
     mysql_query($query) or die("not successfully insert".mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: show your `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be the case that data is not coming into your $_POST['E1'],

then in that case you are executing the foreach for the blank array,
so what all you need to do is

```
if(isset($ele_school) && $ele_school != NULL){
     foreach($ele_school as $ele_school2){
     // your script
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
if (isset($_POST['E1']) {  

    //then use your foreach loop
}
```